# Is msg TopicStatistics deprecated in ros2?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ros1, it was possible to subscribe to /statistics which is of type TopicStatistics
http://docs.ros.org/api/rosgraph_msgs/html/msg/TopicStatistics.html

Is this message & topic available in ros2?
I dont see it listed under ros2 rcl interfaces
https://github.com/ros2/rcl_interfaces/tree/master/rosgraph_msgs

I also see that the ros2 demo for topic monitoring has a different implementation
https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/master/topic_monitor/topic_monitor/scripts/topic_monitor.py

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327901/is-msg-topicstatistics-deprecated-in-ros2?/) by [tb](https://answers.ros.org/users/44017/tb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2019-07-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tb](https://answers.ros.org/users/44017/tb/) on 2019-07-08**:
Found another post that seems to indicate the same thing - absence of message TopicStatistics in ros2
https://answers.ros.org/question/324293/enabling-statistics-in-rqt_graph-for-ros2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, we have neither that feature nor that message yet in ROS 2. We definitely should implement it, as it is a very useful feature in ROS 1, but we just haven't gotten around to it yet.

It would be great to have an issue to track this feature (maybe on https://github.com/ros2/ros2/ since it will span C++, Python, and tooling) and even better would be a pull request :)

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2019-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tb](https://answers.ros.org/users/44017/tb/) on 2019-07-12**:
Thanks for your feedback William
I've opened a feature request as you suggested: https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/744
Perhaps if time permits will definitely look into contributing to it